# How to navigate to the previous page in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

How to navigation to previous page!

I add navigation controller to appDelegate so thought out the application i do have navigation controller.

I hidden navigation Bar and added HeaderView on the top.

// Hidden NavigationBar

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Now customize my header bar with UIView! I hidden navigation Bar and added HeaderView on the top.

Now i added BackButton to the header Bar.  Now i want to navigation pervious page.  Can any one suggest me?

@Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the view is called by a push action, call :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

else if the view is displaying by a modal call :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Use [self.navigationController popviewControllerAnimated :YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this when the user taps the Back button:

```
[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```